# Solve geometric series equation with large terms

Tags: geometric-series

Let $\{a_i\}$ is a geometric sequence with common ratio $r=2/3$. If $a_1+a_2+...+a_{100}=15$, $a_1+a_2+...+a_{99}$?

I think $a_1(1+\frac{2}{3}+...+(\frac{2}{3})^{99})=15 \implies a_1=5$, what wrong?

Comment: **Note**: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}ar^k=a\dfrac{1-r^n}{1-r}$. Here $n=100$.

Answer (score 1):

The sum $1+\frac{2}{3}+...+(\frac{2}{3})^{99} \neq 3$  The limit as the number of terms goes to infinity is $3$, but you have a finite sum here.  I suspect your teacher is expecting an algebraic result, not a calculator one.  It is [very close](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20(2%2F3)%5En%20from%200%20to%2099), but not equal.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You get $a_1\bigg(\frac{1-\color{blue}{(\frac23)^{100}}}{1-\frac23}\bigg)=15\implies a_1=\frac5{1-\color{blue}{(\frac23)^{100}}}$.